# Any offline tool finding broken links can pass login page?

Tags: performance, web-applications, performance-testing, broken-links, xenu

Our team have finished development phase of a web application
And i want to check the whole pages if there is a broken links or not
I try to use a lot of tools such as **Xenu** tool and **LinkChecker** tool
BUT
It *can NOT* navigate pages under the login page
And only home page will checked
Because of **authentication** is required

If there is a way to pass the authentication parameters ("userName" and "password") to the tool
to make it able to navigate pages under login page and check them

Comment: In theory any tools that support cookies can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your login module so that you can pass username and password in the url. Then start the tool from something like this: `http://yourwebsite.com/login?username=...&password=...`. You can then leave the work to the tool and your webapp, supposing your tool is managing cookies correctly (Xenu has an option for that.)

After reading the cookies section in the Xenu FAQ, I realized it can access IE's cookies, so...you can try login in IE then (while the browser is still running) run Xenu, enabling its cookies.

Comment: send authentication values as a `GET` parameters is **NOT** preferred .. but make the Broken link checker tool allowing cookies is the key

Comment: As **Xenu** website recommendation ...  You should not use this option if you have links that delete data,  e.g. a database or a shop - you are risking data loss!!!

Answer (score 0):

The only enterprise-grade solution I found so far is IBM Rational Policy tester. It does a whole lot more than simply checking broken links, but it does it well (spell check, grammar, reg ex, SEO, 508 accessibility, ...). The configuration of the tool is a pain and the UI is incredibly dated too... Having said that, authentication isn't an issue and, once configured, it does the job like a boss.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAUB3_8.5.0/com.ibm.pt.help.doc/helpindex_pt.html